# How can I implement a Speech to Text system in Xamarin Android (Visual Studio) using PocketSphinx library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am building a Speech to Text system and, because of the requiremets, I must use CMUSphinx Speech Recognition.

I try use a native libary (.so) and the wrapper for use it. I have achieved compile and run de code but it doesn't work properly. The code run but it seems that it doesn't record the voice.

I don't know how I have to continue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know nothing of xamarin and (so) this remark may not help, but some experience with the subject of audio I would say: first go check the options of your program. Is there any way to see, or save, the recorded wave ? or a level indicator of some kind ?  If so, checkout level options.. if nothing works, find other software to record voice to samples. If that works, test if the sampling frequency of your speech-to-text program can also be recorded. If not, you can try change the sampling frequency of your program input. Also, make sure to check mono and stereo settings.

Comment: @Goodies Thanks for trying to help me, but it does not help me much. I think the problem is the audio-record-task is canceled early, but I don't know why it happens.